# html body does not capture the entire size of the mobile resolution

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am  trying to make flexible my application, I use 100vw width and 100vh height for my components, in the browser on the computer it is displayed perfectly in any resolution. But as soon as I start using it in mobile resolution, the body draws an empty background below, in the picture I have displayed it with a blue background. Tell me what could be the problem here and how can I solve it? Thanks

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.page {
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
    &_content {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ec7373;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you expecting to get help without showing the relevant HTML and CSS??

Comment: you can use @media for **Responsive**

Comment: if you give your source code, i may can give you a better result !

Comment: @EliotAlderson changed the question

Comment: if you give html also, that, we can help you and undestand what div is `.page` ..

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the `box-sizing` css property on your `.page` class to define your height and width and override possible padding and margin

like so :

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.page {
  box-sizing : border-box;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
    &_content {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ec7373;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

You can refer to [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#box-sizing) but please do share the HTML and CSS as we can't really help without being able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: This is not suitable, I have a lot of styles in this application and this is the code from my work, I cannot submit it. The only thing I noticed is that this bar disappears if there is a lot of content on the right side of the page (not the sidebar)

Comment: one more fact, this bug is only in android, in ios everything works fine

Comment: I can understand the confidentiality clause, however this seems to be a cross browser issue, I'm not asking for sources, but for a reproduced and simplified problem, you can invent a different context, replace everything that links back to your work... 
I cannot debug or help you with your problem like this. It's the same for the SO community. We're not seers but developpers, AFAIK your `.page` div could be in another div with a smaller size and an hidden overflow... Anyway good luck !

Comment: Do not confuse the W3C (standards agency) with W3Schools (advertising-riddled error-prone tutorial mill who take advantage of having a similar name)